# boost assign list_of does not work with double literals?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use boost's `list_of` to initialize a `vector<double>`, but it seems the vector ends up with the integer values.

I start from the example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/assign/doc/index.html#complicated and change the `score_type` to `vector<double>` and add a few floating point literals. Here's the new code:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
  typedef vector<double>                   score_type;
  typedef map<string,score_type>        team_score_map;
  typedef pair<string,score_type>       score_pair;

  team_score_map group1, group2;
  //
  // method 1: using 'insert()'
  //
  insert( group1 )( "Denmark", list_of(1.1)(1) )
    ( "Germany", list_of(0)(0) );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group1.size() == 2 );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group1[ "Denmark" ][1] == 1 );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group1[ "Denmark" ][0] == 1.1 );

  //
  // method 2: using 'list_of()'
  //
  group2 = list_of< score_pair >
    ( "Norway",  list_of(1)(5.9) )
    ( "Andorra", list_of(1)(1) );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group2.size() == 2 );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group2[ "Norway" ][0] == 1 );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group2[ "Norway" ][1] == 5 );
  BOOST_ASSERT( group2[ "Norway" ][1] == 5.9 );

  return 0;
}
```

The last assert of method 1 `insert` works fine, but the last assert of method 2 `list_of` fails. I tried initializing with `((double)5.9)` and `(5.9f)` to no avail.

I guess for now I can work-around by using `insert`.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

(I am aware of C++11 initializer list, but I want to understand what's going on here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't tell `list_of` what type to expect, it guesses from its first invocation:

```
list_of
    (0) // int
    (0.5) // oops, already decided int
```

You can specify:

```
list_of<double>(1)(5.9)
```

Or you can make sure that the first invocation is sufficient to guess:

```
list_of(1.0)(5.9)
```

Comment: Ahh! I should have looked at the list_of header. Thanks.